# Partial replacement for a searched regex in notepad++ while search criteria contains not match condition

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++, regular-language, inverse

I am trying to do a find and replace on notepad++ for data shaped as below, unfortunately for now I am not successful.

My data look like this (keeping in mind this is a huge CSV):

```
1223752, filed1Row1, filed2Row1, filed3
100% Row1
1223698 filed1Row2, filed2Row2, filed3
200$ Row3
```

Expected output

```
1223752, filed1Row1, filed2Row1, filed3 100% Row1
1223698 filed1Row2, filed2Row2, filed3 200$ Row3
```

I am trying to remove the new line making the first row complete.

This is the search I am doing:

```
\n(\d)(\d)(\d)[^(\d)]
replacing this with
$1$2$3
```

However this is removing the non digit characters (`$%`) I want to keep these and only remove the new line.

Comment: Please show the expected output

Comment: Try `\n(\d\d\d[^\w\n] Row\d+)$` --> `$1`

Comment: Thanks @TheLostMind , expected output added...

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew unfortunately did not work...

Comment: That means you have 1) CRLF endings, use `\R`, or/and 2) There may be other words than `Row`  + digits. `\R(\d{3}[^\d\r\n])` -> `$1` should work then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\R(?=\d{3}\D\h)`
- Replace with:  (a space)
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\R      : any kind of linebreak (\n or \r or \r\n)
(?=     : lookahead
  \d{3} : 3 digits
  \D    : a NON-digit
  \h    : a horizontal space
)       : end lookahead
```

Comment: This also works, thanks for your help and the explanation, this is most useful...

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
\r\n(?=\d{3}\D)
```

with single space

I used `\r` in because of the windows environment. I've tested it on my npp and it works. In the below demo, it is absent.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kcYZrD/1)

Comment: @OmarQA - Glad it helped.

Comment: Thanks @GurV, the \r was not needed since the \n was in original data in side the field.... but it worked perfectly without it so thank you...